# /cars.xhtml @18,74 binding="#{carBean.cars}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'carBean' resolved to null

Tags: jsf-2, javabeans, cdi

I have a problem with JSF 2.2 and CDI, I don't know if weld is necessary because I am using classfish and it already has CDI, somebody has any idea what's going on?

The error is that:

```
/cars.xhtml @18,74 binding="#{carBean.cars}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'carBean' resolved to null
```

My managerbean is:

```java
@Named
public class CarBean implements Serializable {

    private List<Car> cars;

    @Inject
    private CarRepositoryImpl dao;

    private HtmlDataTable dataTable;

    public void setDataTable(HtmlDataTable dataTable)
    {
      this.dataTable = dataTable;
    }

    public HtmlDataTable getDataTable()
    {
      return dataTable;
    }

    public EntityManager entityManager;

    public CarController() {
        this.dao = new CarRepositoryImpl(entityManager);
        this.setCarros(this.dao.findAll());
        Car car = new Car();
        car.setDescricao("Teste");
        this.cars.add(car);
    }

    public void setCars(List<Car> cars) {
        this.cars = cars;
    }

    public List<Car> getCar(){
        return this.cars;
    }

}
```

My JSF page is:

```html
<ui:define name="title">
    cars sample
</ui:define>

<ui:define name="content">
    <f:view>
        <h:form>
            <h:dataTable value="#{carBean.cars}" var="car"
                         binding="#{carBean.cars}">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputLabel>description</h:outputLabel>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{car.description}"></h:outputLabel>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </f:view>
</ui:define>
```

Comment: Do you have a `beans.xml` in the `WEB-INF` directory of the WAR file?

Comment: No, I don't. is it still necessary even with CDI?

Comment: Yes it is a required file.  In Java EE6 it can be blank/empty, Java EE 7 it's a bit more robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To activate cdi Bean parsing, you have to put an empty XML file into the WEB-INF directory. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbnz.html